# DSharpPlus | Assigning Roles To Members Not Resolving

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

Using DSharpPLus `4.3.0-nightly-01181`

```
[Command("ping")]
[Description("returns pong")]
[RequireChannel(ChannelCheckMode.Any, "test")]
public async Task Ping(CommandContext ctx)
{
     var role = ctx.Guild.GetRole(1036940809272033290);
     await ctx.Member.GrantRoleAsync(role).ConfigureAwait(false);
     await ctx.RespondAsync("Pong").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

So when the command is fired, the role exists and is not null, the member exists and is not null.

The `GrantRoleAsync` line is fired, it does not throw an exception but nor does it execute and thus the last line is never fired.

For testing purposes the bot has **ALL** intents and has administrator rights.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Have you tried the stable build instead of the nightly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the bot user can only assign roles lower than its role